# Restricting ICMP using iptables

Tags: iptables, icmp

I have the following rule,which i believe will restrict icmp packets to 1/s.

```
:INPUT DROP [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [7:988]
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type any -m limit --limit 1/sec -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 11.x.x.71/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 11.x.x.65/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 11.x.x.66/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
```

But when i ping this host with "ping -i .001 " all the packets are reaching this machine and on

**iptables-nvL** DROP counter is not incrementing.Whats wrong with this rule

Comment: -i .001 seems to be an invalid interval, how are you able to do that?

Comment: ping -i .0001 destination,i can see more packets are being transmitted.

Comment: my system spits out: "ping: -i interval too short: Operation not permitted" when trying to do that.

Comment: try as root normal user may not be able to do that

Comment: You say the `DROP` counter is not incrementing.  Is the counter on the `RELATED,ESTABLISHED` ACCEPT incrementing?

Comment: Yes DROP counter is not incrementing,but State counter is incrementing.but if i remove state rule everything will work as expected  but then i have to manually ACCEPT each ip.

Comment: @MadHatter changing state to ESTABLISHED didnt change anything.

Comment: No, Iain's answer explains better what's going on (and, I think, is the simplest possible fix).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that you accept one packet (which implicitly is state NEW and then attempt to apply a limit rule. The limit probably does work however the `RELATED,ESTABLISHED` rule later down the line will probably mess things up for you.

You have two options:

1. Set the related and established rule on a per-protocol basis.
2. Make ICMP traffic of that type not trackable by state tracking.

*Given the tables are there right now...*

**Set the related and established rule on a per-protocol basis.**

```
iptables -D INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -m tcp -p tcp -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -m udp -p udp -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

**Make ICMP traffic of that type not trackable by state tracking.**

```
iptables -t raw -I PREROUTING -m icmp -p icmp --icmp-type any -j NOTRACK
```

Comment: Thanks it worked,i thought icmp packets do not have states

Comment: The iptables state engine isn't TCP-sequence-number based, it infers state from synchronicity.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to add an explicit DROP rule for ICMP after your rate limiting rule

```
-A INPUT -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type any -m limit --limit 1/sec -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -j DROP
```

This is because subsequent packets are considered ESTABLISHED and your later rule

```
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

allows them before they get dropped by the policy.